# Accessing a bucket outside my account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

There's a specific bucket (not from my account) which I want to have access. The authors of the bucket have a github site [here](https://github.com/ewels/AWS-iGenomes), and they made the data accessible. The problem comes when I try to `aws s3 ls` which I get the following error:

```
aws s3 \
--region eu-west-1 \
ls s3://ngi-igenomes/igenomes/Homo_sapiens/Ensembl/GRCh37/Annotation/Genes/
```

`A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied`

This is somewhat strange because the bucket has a `Requester Pays` policy meaning that access is limited to authenticated requests only, and I have a user with an access key, secret access key and my account/s3 buckets/etc ... is in same region (eu-west) than the bucket I'm trying to access.

So, I'm asking for help as I do not understand why I don't have access. 
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: u might not be having ListObjects permissions; this is a different permission than GetObject

Comment: I reviewed my IAM policies and actually I have the following:{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}, which I think includes the ListObjects attribute, but correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: Having ListObjects permission on your IAM user is not sufficient (consider the ramifications if it were sufficient to list all buckets in all AWS accounts). The target bucket must also have a policy allowing you to invoke ListObjects against the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Your error says: `A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied`

This means that **you have not been granted permission to list that bucket** (or at least that path within the bucket).

Since the bucket is in a different AWS account, the only way these permissions can be granted to you is via an **Amazon S3 bucket policy**. Only the **owner of the bucket** can configure the bucket policy (or, more accurately, any user within that account who has the necessary permissions to edit the Bucket Policy).

(If it was in the **same account**, it would be possible to also use an **IAM User policy** to grant access.)

Alternatively, the bucket owners could create an **IAM Role** that has the necessary permissions and they could configure a Trust relationship to your normal IAM User. You would assume the role and then access the bucket. However, this would defeat the Requester Pays capabilities because they would be charged for such access.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when weather bucket has requester pays policy and you don't include requester pays header explicitly in your request